# I see a dot after -rwxr-xr-x

Tags: linux, redhat

Whenever I issue `ls -al` command in my server I see a dot after -rwxr-xr-x like -

```
-rwxr-xr-x.
```

Can anyone tell me what that means? I can't get any clue from the internet.

Comment: Can you list which UNIX version you're using (and distribution and release if it's Linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `info ls`, under "*What information is listed?*", the "*-l*" flag:

> GNU 'ls' uses a '.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
> security context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
> marked with a '+' character.

Answer (score 3):

FYI - You can view the SELinux security contexts with the `ls -Z` option.

```
# ls -alZ
dr-xr-x---. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 .
dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0      ..
-rw-------. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-------  root root ?                                .bash_history
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 .cshrc
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 .tcshrc
```